# Join, all rows from one table and first row from the other table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables properties and property_images

```
where properties.pid = property_images.pid
```

A property can have more than one images, I have to select all the properties and the first property image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
    t1.* ,
    t2.image
from properties as t1 
left join (
           select 
               min(id), 
               pid, 
               image 
           from property_images  
           group by pid) as t2 
on t2.pid = t1.pid
```

Comment: you need to select pid if you have to include it in your group by clause

Comment: Also add t2.image  in `SELECT t1.*,t2.image` and correct ON statement: you use t1 on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from property a 
left join ( select * from property_Images b group by pid) s on s.pid=a.pid ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    pro.* 
from properties as pro 
left join (
           select 
               min(id),
               pid,
               image 
           from property_images  
           group by pid) as pro_img 
on pro.pid = pro_img.pid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *  
from properties as t1 
left join property_images t2 on (t1.pid=t2.pid) 
where t2.id in
           (select min(id) from property_images where property_images.pid=t2.pid)
```

**OR** Suppose there is an unique key ID in property_images:

```
select *  
from properties as t1 
left join (select min(id) minID, pid from property_images group by pid) t2
   on (t1.pid=t2.pid)  
left join property_images t3 on (t2.minID=t3.id)
```

Select which one is faster on your DB.